# Saving Leaflet Draw geometry into PostgreSQL with PHP?

Tags: php, postgresql, leaflet

I try in an attempt to save a geometry obtained with leaflet draw in a PostgreSQL database via PHP. I get an error

> ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)

and I can't figure out what's wrong with my PHP code. Any ideas?

Part of my JS:

```
var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(drawnItems);
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
        draw: {
            circle: true,
          },
         edit: {
             featureGroup: drawnItems
         }
     }).addTo(map);
     map.addControl(drawControl);
    map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
        var type = e.layerType;
        var layer = e.layer;

        var shape = layer.toGeoJSON()
        var shape_for_db = JSON.stringify(shape);
        
        drawnItems.addLayer(e.layer);
        
        console.log(e);
        var latitude=layer.getLatLng().lat;
        var longitude=layer.getLatLng().lng;
        fetch('enregistr.php?latitude='+latitude+'&longitude='+longitude)

});
```

And this is my PHP code :

```
<?php
$latitude = $_GET["lat"];
$longitude = $_GET["lng"];

$conn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=admin");

// prepare and bind

$stmt = "INSERT INTO c_map  (latitude, longitude) VALUES (?,?)";
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $latitude, $longitude);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

In Postgres I have a table with 3 columns: `id, latitude, longitude`. The connection is ok.

My goal is to be able to save a geometry (polygon or marker) in a PostgreSQL table and to be able to save properties in it, but that's another story.

Comment: Check the server's error logs to see what the error message was.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I didn't know the server's error logs and it's so helpful ! It's worked when I deleted bind_param and use $lat,$long instead of "?".

Comment: Dude _no_. You just took a step backwards and introduced a SQL injection vulnerability into your application.